# Add UIActivityIndicatorView to UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to add an `UIActivityIndicatorView` to `UIActionsSheet` in this way:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:nil
                                  delegate:sharedInstance
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in moreStructure)
   {
       NSString *value = [dict valueForKey:TITLE_PARAMETER];
       [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:value];
   }
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [moreStructure count];
    [actionSheet showInView:((SectionViewController *)sharedInstance.currentViewController).view];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 500, 15, 15);
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [actionSheet addSubview:activityView];
```

When the `UIActionSheet` appears, however, I do not see an `UIActivityIndicatorView` on it. Please, help me.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to do this?

Comment: lol true I am curious to know to , usually people add it to an alertview or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have try this and this is working... Please check frame of activityView... because its y is 500...

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:nil
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Test"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Test"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 5, 15, 15);
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [actionSheet addSubview:activityView];

    activityView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    actionSheet.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: You are right, thank you. I was not thinking that frame of UIActionSheet begins from first button.

Answer (score 1):

```
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 500, 15, 15);
```

// this so this above must change

```
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 400);
```